# Can you end concentration on a spell during someone else's turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, concentration, spellcasting

Say for example, my group is fighting a group of archers. Bard casts Darkness. We determine that the archers can see through the darkness, as they are hitting each of their shots. Can the bard end concentration on the Darkness spell the moment the party realizes that they can see through the darkness or does he have to wait until his turn?

Comment: @Purple Monkey, only moderately annoyed that I don't find these questions when I search for them.

Comment: Try searching on Google instead of the stack. I've found the stack's search to be underwhelming :)